# Follow up question on the nature of the $\sum \limits _{n\geq 1}\frac{2^n\mod n}{n^2}$ series

Tags: sequences-and-series

A few years ago, I have asked about the nature of the following series: $$\sum \limits _{n\geq 1}\frac{2^n\mod n}{n^2}$$ It was proven by user https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9340/sangchul-lee [Does the sum $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{2^n\operatorname{mod} n}{n^2}$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1965012/does-the-sum-sum-n-geq-1-frac2n-operatornamemod-nn2-converge) that the series diverges. A similar question was answered here: [Sum of the series $\sum_{n\geq1} \frac{P(n) \bmod Q(n)} {n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1965123/sum-of-the-series-sum-n-geq1-fracpn-bmod-qn-n2?noredirect=1&lq=1) and a more general statement was analyzed here:  [Convergence of the series $\sum_ {n\geq1} \frac {(f(n) +P(n)) \pmod {Q(n)}} {D(n)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1974148/convergence-of-the-series-sum-n-geq1-frac-fn-pn-pmod-qn-dn?noredirect=1&lq=1) .

I am now asking if:

$$\sum \limits _{n\geq 1}\frac{(2^n\mod P(n))\mod n}{n^2}$$
diverges, for:

1. P(n)=n^2+2*n+5
2. P(n)=n^2+3*n-2

The difference between the 2 is that the first has a positive remainder and the second has a negative remainder.
In both cases we work under the intuitive heuristic that $2^n$ is Equi distributed in 0..P(n)-1.
In the first case the remainder of P(n) divided by n is 5, so we shall have a slightly higher chance to get 0,1,2,3,4 which are constant. The sum of these constants over $n^2$ should be finite but as n increases the likelihood of getting them also decreases to 0.
In the second case where the remainder of P(n) divided by n is -2 and the 0..n-3 values are a bit more likely than the last 2 values, but this only move the n/2 average a little lower.
So, by these arguments assuming the heuristics hold the series should still diverge.
Am I correct? Is there a reason why the heuristics should not hold?